# GCC: segmentation fault when using delete

Tags: c++, gcc

I use `delete` to remove an object that is created using the`new []`. It is undefined behavior. But why in the next program, this operation leads to a different result? In the second case, segmentation fault, and nothing in the first.

```
class A {
    public:
        A() {std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;}
        ~A() {std::cout << "A::~A()" <<std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    //1:
    char* pc = new char[5];
    delete pc; //OK

    //2:
    A* pa = new A[5];
    delete pa; //Segmentation fault
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `delete[] pa` because you intent to delete an *array*.

Comment: `A* pc = new char[5];` should not compile...

Answer (score 3):

> But why in the next program, this operation leads to a different result?

You've answered that yourself in the previous sentence:

> It is undefined behavior.

It seems that you are expecting the program to be predictable. UB is not predictable. Both "OK" and "Segmentation fault" are possible behaviours, and neither behaviour is guaranteed.